# Can I enter the UK for 24 hours from a Schengen area, holding an Indian passport?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas, schengen-visas

I am travelling to Poland and Netherlands, flying on the 25th June, holding a Schengen business visa.

For the weekend, can I plan to go to the UK (just Sunday)? I am not planning to stay overnight. One day return trip. I hold an Indian passport (no USA visa stamped).

Can I get a transit visa for 24 hours with this?

Comment: No, you have to apply the visa in advance in the country you are living.

Comment: Are you planning to visit UK on your (extended) way from Poland to Netherlands?

Comment: Maybe from Amsterdam to London by Eurostar

Answer (score 29):

If you're making a day trip to the UK and then back to the place you arrived from, then you're *not in transit*, and a transit visa wouldn't do you any good.

You'd need a **Standard Visitor Visa**, which must be applied for in advance. The 8 days you have until you leave will probably not be enough for this application to be completed unless you pay for super-crash-priority service.

Thus, realistically, no, you can't go to the UK.

Answer (score 17):

Transit visas are for entering a country where the only purpose – or, at least, the main purpose – is to connect to transport to a third country. Your purpose for visiting the UK is purely tourism: you want to spend a few hours visiting and then return to the country you came from. You can't do that on a transit visa: you need a Standard Visitor Visa.

Purely as a matter of opinion, there are millions of things to see in Schengen, and I wouldn't go to the expense and trouble of getting a visa for a few hours' touristing. Go to Paris, instead. Or stay in Amsterdam: there's plenty to see there, too.

Comment: Funny idea: can I ask for a transit visa if I book boat tickets from Netherlands to UK and then from UK to Ireland? I will surely need to "transit" from one port to the other ;)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ No. Because of the Common Travel Area, you [need a Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa) (or an Irish visa marked "BC" or "BC BIVS") to pass through the UK on the way to Ireland. In principle, you could use a transit visa to take ferried from the Netherlands to the UK and then onwards to France or Spain, but an immigration officer would probably be very suspicious, especially if it emerged that the only thing you were going to do there was get on a flight straight back to the Netherlands.

Comment: Also, you need to get a transit visa in advance, too, so it wouldn't really help, except that it's cheaper.

Comment: Yeah, thnx. I suspected that my plan was flawed, pity ;(

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ There's also the fact that I think it's illegal to 'game' the system like that. Something about misrepresenting your intentions, I think, though I'm no lawyer.